# ActiveMQ user config - which file does what?

Tags: activemq-classic

There are many locations for defining usernames and passwords:

- `activemq.xml`
- `users.properties`
- `groups.properties`
- `credentials.properties`
- `credentials-enc.properties`

I am using `authorizationPlugin` in `activemq.xml`. I figure user/pass is for specific destinations

1. How do the groups in `authorizationPlugin` relate to `groups.properties`?
2. When are `credentials.properties` and `credentials-enc.properties` being used?
3. How will the password from `user.properties` be used in contrast to the `credentials.properties` and `credentials-enc.properties`?
4. Is it necessary that user/pass/group from files match (apart from `users.properties`/`groups.properties`)

Basically I want

1. user/pass on TCP port
2. user/pass on web console
3. user/pass per destination

Comment: There's too many questions here. You need to narrow it down significantly. Keep in mind that you can ask multiple individual questions.

Comment: @user1782357 im also confused like you. Still looking for answers. :(

Answer (score 3):

A good reference here: [ActiveMQ Security](https://activemq.apache.org/security)

I suggest starting with getting user+password how you want, and then add authorization. The authorization is generally done by group or role tied to a destination or a destination wildcard. Be sure to create a 'allusers' group or 'allrole' as you generally want to grant all users access to the topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.> destination wildcard.

The different files in the distribution are provided by different sample setups.

Assuming the Apache ActiveMQ distribution

- conf/login.config defines which files ActiveMQ uses for authenticating and authorizing users and groups
- conf/jetty-realm.properties defines which files the web console uses for authenticating and authorizing web console access

Note for future readers-- there is a JIRA to consolidate all auth in ActiveMQ to one set of files. Follow JIRA [AMQ-8391](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-8391)

Keep in mind-- many of these 'static' named users and groups are for developer-local testing or for running a broker in a unit test. Generally, production systems will want to use JAAS.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question fully. I'm also confused with those many props files. What about credentials and credentails-enc.properties ? How are they different from users.properties ? Can you clarify..

Comment: "The different files in the distribution are provided by different sample setups." -- the various documentation and samples configs in the distribution provide users with options of how to setup and manage security. Different services can have different user access-- JMS, JMX or HTTP services. The decisions on how those services are setup dictates which files are used. If you use JAAS (ie login.conf) it defines conf/users.properties, group.properties). If you wire authn or authz direct to activemq.xml credentials or credentials-enc could be used.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So basically for simple amq broker authentication, credentials* props are enough and we don't need users/groups props. And for Webconsole authentication, jetty-realm.properties file is enough. Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: If you use the jaasAuthenticationPlugin you need users+groups file as named in the conf/login.config. Jetty uses the realm.properties by default for the web console. If you mean simpleAuthenticationPlugin, those users and groups are statically configured in the activemq.xml and no properties file is used at all. If you load the conf/credentials.properties file using a Spring org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean, you can then reference users and groups from credentials.properties as variables in the activemq.xml.